# New row after every 6th column excel

Tags: excel

I have data in a row. Let us A1 to XFD1 and I want to split my
data by every 6th column. That means A1-F1 as it is, from  G1-L1 should shift to A2-F2, and so on.

Example:

```
A B C D E F A B C D E F A B C D E F A B C D E F A B C D E F A B C D E F
```

I need these like this:

```
A B C D E F 
A B C D E F
A B C D E F
A B C D E F
```

Answer (score 0):

This VBA routine will work.

```
Sub SplitData()
    Dim data As Range, arr() As Variant
    Dim row As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer

    Set data = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlToRight))
    arr = data
    data.ClearContents

    row = 1

    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 1 To data.Columns.Count Step 6
        For j = 0 To 5
            Cells(row, j + 1) = arr(1, i + j)
        Next j
        row = row + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```